# How do I subtract two numbers using Swift?

Tags: swift, uibutton, subtraction

I am trying to subtract to numbers that are generated randomly. I am having some problems with the code. Here is the code I have as of now:

```
@IBAction func subtractionButton(sender: UIButton){
    operationLabel.text = "-"
    var total == ("\(randomNumber)" - "\(secondRandomNumber)")
}
```

The error is: 'UInt8.Type' does not have a member
named 'covertStringInterpolationSegment'. It is on the var total line.

I am pretty new to Swift so I may be missing something very obvious.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need this with string interpolation

```
@IBAction func subtractionButton(sender: UIButton){

    operationLabel.text = "-"
    var subTot = randomNumber - secondRandomNumber
    var total = "\(subTot)"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have double equal sign(comparing sign) to store the value, thats wrong and you are substracting strings, thats the reason it returns weird values.
Try this:

```
@IBAction func subtractionButton(sender: UIButton){
    operationLabel.text = "-"
    var total = randomNumber - secondRandomNumber
    println(total)//print result of substraction
}
```